# Xcode 4.2 IOS 5, Cant select provision in Target

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I am having a weird issue with my profiles. For my project, i have all the provisioning profiles in order. Developer, Distribution & Release, everything seems to be fine, no errors, no discrepancies  in keychain or organizer.

However, i am able to select the correct profiles, Developer and Distribution for the project settings; but for the target settings i cannot select the distribution profile. They are greyed out and show "does not match application identifier" message. But my bundle identifier is exactly the same (case sensitive) as i have created it in the portal.

I have tried removing and adding the profiles; still the same.

One thing, i noticed however is - when i try using "Automatic Provisioning" from xcode it is removing adhoc and appstore profiles from the portal; i have no idea why.

Again, my bundle identifiers are correct, i picked the correct app in the portal.

any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through my old project and comparing it with the current one; i have noticed the project name being added to the bundle identifier. So effectively my bundle identifier is becoming something like com.veeru.mface.mfaceproject where as xcode expects it to be com.veeru.mface only. 
I had to remove the {BUNDLE IDENTIFIER} attached to the bundle id project's plist and xcode immediately saw the profiles properly.

Caught me by surprise cause i never had these issues previously; And still cant' figure out why xcode removes my profiles when i do a "Automatic provisioning" refresh.